# Mathematica: is it possible to put AxesLabel for 3D graphics at the end of the axes as in 2D?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

According to

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/AxesLabel.html

it says

"By default, axes labels in two-dimensional graphics are placed at the ends of the axes. In three-dimensional graphics, they are aligned with the middles of the axes."

I wanted to put the axes labels at the end of the axes also for my 3D plots, since that makes it easy for me to see which axes is now where when I do rotations and such on the 3D objects.

I was not able to find a trick to do it.  Here is an example

```
g=Graphics3D[
{
  Cuboid[{-.1,-.1,-.1},{.1,.1,.1}],
         {Red,PointSize[.03],Point[{3,0,0}]},
         {Black,PointSize[.03],Point[{0,3,0}]},
         {Blue,PointSize[.03],Point[{0,0,3}]}
         },
         AxesOrigin->{0,0,0},
         PlotRange->{{-3,3},{-3,3},{-3,3}},
         Axes->True,
         AxesLabel->{"X","Y","Z"},
         LabelStyle->Directive[Bold,Red,16],
         PreserveImageOptions->False,
         Ticks->None,
         Boxed->False
  ]
```

Also, it says that the axes labels for 3D are supposed to be in the 'middle' of the axes.

But looking at the resulting Graphics3D, it does not look to me the labels are in the middle at all. Might be a scaling thing, not sure now, but it looks like the labels are too close to the origin.

thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could draw the labels manually, at the location of your choosing:

`Graphics3D[
  { Cuboid[{-.1,-.1,-.1},{.1,.1,.1}]
  , Text[Style["X", Bold, Red, 16], {3, 0, 0}]
  , Text[Style["Y", Bold, Black, 16], {0, 3, 0}]
  , Text[Style["Z", Bold, Blue, 16], {0, 0, 3}]
  }
, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}
, PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}
, Axes -> True
, PreserveImageOptions -> False
, Ticks -> None
, Boxed -> False
]`

[image: axis labels]

Comment: Thanks Wreach, Yes, good solution, that is what I ended up doing! I gave up trying to find out how, and AxesLabel was giving my headach since they show up in wrong places. Please see other thread I have. +1